# concatenate several JSON responses

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, concatenation

I try to concatenate several JSON-responses from a XHR.

I have a list of XHR I want to go through and put all the results in the same CSV. I understand that I should probably write to CSV outside the loop but initially I just want it to work. I have made two comments at the end, this is the part I don't get to work. I also added a break at the end so you don't have to go trough everything.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import csv
import json
    


h = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

#VARIABLES
i=0

projects = "https://cdn-search-standard-prod.azureedge.net/api/v1/tags/all/2af3c43b-98aa-49d8-b4ff-da6d5a992751" 

y=requests.get(projects,headers=h).json()
df=pd.json_normalize(y)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Documents\Python Scripts\ListOfProjects_20200628.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')

export=[]
i=29

for y in y:
    print(str(df.id[i]))
    u = "https://cdn-search-standard-prod.azureedge.net/api/v1/search/getstageobjects/"+str(df.id[i])
    i = i+1
    units = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()
    dp=pd.DataFrame(units)
    dp = pd.json_normalize(units)

    dp.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Documents\Python Scripts\Units_20200628.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
    #export = pd.concat([export,dp], ignore_index=False, sort=False)
    #export.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Documents\Python Scripts\Units_20200628.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
    break
```

Comment: the first line of your code looks funny: "for y in y". also, what's h? Please include all the code one would need to reproduce your issue / question.

Comment: OK, will do. I just tried to be smart and limit the amount of rows :-)

Comment: That would be good, too. If there's too much code, reduce it to something simpler.

Comment: Roy2012, I have updated it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Keep all the 'partial' dataframes in a list, and then create a single large dataframe using `pd.concat`. You can then save this large dataframe using `to_csv`. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
df_list = []

for y in y[:10]: # for development purpose - iterate over 10 URLs only
    print(str(df.id[i]))
    u = "https://cdn-search-standard-prod.azureedge.net/api/v1/search/getstageobjects/"+str(df.id[i])
    i = i+1
    units = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()
    dp=pd.DataFrame(units)
    dp = pd.json_normalize(units)
    df_list.append(dp)

res = pd.concat(df_list)
res.to_csv("final_result.csv")
```

Comment: Great! Exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Can you also shortly give me an advice on how I can add a column to my csv (to the very left) where I store the project ID (the one i am iterating over), so I can filter out different projects in the CSV I am creating?

Comment: Before appending it to the list, do dp["project_id"] = 123. put whatever you want instead of 123.

Comment: The ID in the response with the list of projects is "id", and the id for units where I append is also "id". I assume that will be an issue? Can i do like dp[y.id]?

Comment: For one of the URLs you're downloading, y["id"] is d933ae51-bc42-e611-8139-c4346bad5070. What you can do it dp["proj_id] = y["id"]. All the rows in this specific dataframe will have this value as proj_id

Comment: It seems to work partly fine. It put proj_id in the last column, which I can live with. But i ran it now for 30 entities and got different numbers of columns and ordered in a slightly different way. I assume this is because that all columns doesn't exists in all projects? Will that be an issue or will it be correct anyway? Do I have to pre-define which columns I would like to have?

Comment: I saw the fact that different JSON have different columns. Don't think it's an issue - but I'll verify again. (Checked. Not an issue at all).